# dynamic form dropdown Json/JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm sure it's something basic but does anyone know why my drop-down list is not populating?

jQuery file:

```
 $(document).ready (function() {

    $.getJSON("mars-get-countries.php", success = function (data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

        $("#selectcountry").append(options);
    });
    });
```

HTML form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectcountry">Country of Residence</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="selectcountry">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see no reason what it's not working!!

The `mars-get-countries.php` file works fine when I run it returns the country.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console? Verified that the expected result is being returned from the network inspector tool? Added any debug `console.log()` calls?

Comment: can you paste the response that is received from the `mars-get-countries.php`

Comment: can you paste your json list

Comment: I do need to check the console.log() could your recommend a decent inspector tool add on for chrome? I do believe it would help if I could see what's happening when the code is  being run. When the php code is run it returns the country list. Not sure how it paste the Json list?

Comment: there is `log4js` framework that can generate log file by capturing all `console.log` statements or warnings if you like to

Comment: Okay, I will have a look into that then. The good dies look alright though doesn't it? I think it must be summat small I missing.